# Failed insert data to database with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Not showing error, but failed to insert
and in my database the data is not inserted.
I'm newbie with CI.

this is my
**Controller**

```
class Register extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('m_register');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('user/register');
    }

    public function daftar_akun(){

        $username = $this->input->post('reg_username');
        $password = $this->input->post('reg_password');
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $no_telp = $this->input->post('no_telp');
        $nama_lengkap = $this->input->post('nama_lengkap');
        $no_ktp = $this->input->post('no_ktp');
        $alamat = $this->input->post('alamat');
        $role_id = 3;
        $status = 0;

        $data = array(
            'username'=> $username,
            'password' => $password,
            'email' => $email,
            'no_telp' => $no_telp,
            'nama_lengkap' => $nama_lengkap,
            'no_ktp' => $no_ktp,
            'alamat' => $alamat,
            'role_id' => $role_id,
            'status' => $status
            );
        $this->m_register->register_akun($data);
        redirect(base_url("login"));
    }
}
```

this is my **Model**

```
class M_register extends CI_Model{

    function register_akun($data){
        $this->db->insert('user',$data);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you getting any error messages?

Comment: add this line after your insert query `$error = $this->db->error();` print this and check what are you getting?

Comment: still not working, and i didnt get any error message

Comment: @prakashtank showing this Array ( [code] => 0 [message] => )

Comment: check also this : `echo $this->db->last_query(); ` it will return the last executed query.

Comment: @first check your data array and check if you even request this function ;), because your code looks fine imho

Comment: @prakashtank showing this Array ( [code] => 0 [message] => ) INSERT INTO `user` (`username`, `password`, `email`, `no_telp`, `nama_lengkap`, `no_ktp`, `alamat`, `role_id`, `status`) VALUES ('hihihi', '12345', 'hehe@gmail.com', '123123123', 'ohwhwhw', '1239081923', 'bnd', 3, 0)

Comment: now paste this query in your database editor and check

Comment: @prakashtank oh i understand now, thank you so muchhh

Comment: Do you have the table `user` created in your database?

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning any thing in model page. Please try this one.

```
function register_akun($data){
    if($this->db->insert('user',$data)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a check on your model function to see the last id entered (if a record is inserted). something like:

```
public function insert($data)
         {
             $db = $this->db;
             $db->insert('', $data);
             $id = $db->insert_id();

             if ($id > 0)
             {
                 return $id;
             }
             else
             {
                 return false;
             }
         }
```

But before calling this function, give a var_dump of your $ data array in the daftar_akun () function to see if it is correctly filled. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

For error showing please set error reporting 1 in index.php at root of your codeigniter project. it will be help full for you.
like

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
/*
*---------------------------------------------------------------
* ERROR REPORTING
*---------------------------------------------------------------
*
* Different environments will require different levels of error  reporting.
* By default development will show errors but testing and live will hide them.
*/

if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
{
switch (ENVIRONMENT)
{
    case 'development':
        error_reporting(1);
    break;

    case 'testing':
    case 'production':
        error_reporting(1);
    break;

    default:
        exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
    }
}
```